# Why does this scala fold return Equals types?

Tags: scala

I'm trying to return a map in scala. Here's my code:

```
    val interestRegEx = """(\w+) Interests \((.+ Interest)\)""".r
    val singleAttributes = Seq("Sport Interests (Some Interest):Running,Swimming","Something else:True")
    val interests = singleAttributes.map { x =>
      // e.g. ("Sport Interests (Some Interest)", "Running,Swimming") should
      // result in ("Sport Running" -> "Some Interest", "Sport Swimming" -> "Some Interest")
      val attVal = x.split(':')

      attVal(0) match {
        case interestRegEx(interestProduct, interestAmount) =>
          Some(attVal(1).split(",").map { i =>
            Map(s"$interestProduct $i" -> interestAmount)
          }.reduce(_ ++ _))
        case _ => None
      }
    }.fold(Map[String, String]())(_) //.reduce(_ + _)
```

The problem is trying to reduce the collection to a single Map[String, String]. I thought the fold might work, but since it doesn't perhaps I'd even need to add a `reduce(_ + _)` afterwards, but that doesn't work either.

The part I don't understand is that IntelliJ tells me that `interests` has type `((Equals, Equals) => Equals) => Equals`. WTF? Where are these `Equals` coming from, and why isn't it just adding all of the Maps together to return a Map containing all keys & values?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If we simplify your example we will get:

```
  val interests = Seq[String]().map { x =>
    Option[Map[String, String]](Map("k" -> "v"))
  }.fold(Map[String, String]())(_)
```

This means that we are trying to `fold` `Seq[Option[Map[String, String]]]` with initial value `Map[String, String]()`:

```
def fold[A1 >: A](z: A1)(op: (A1, A1) => A1): A1 = foldLeft(z)(op)
```

From `fold` definition we can see that compiler expects that `Option[Map[String, String]]` (each value in folding) and `Map[String, String]` (init value) should be of the same type.

If you inspect `Option` hierarchy you will see:

`Option` -> `Product` -> `Equals`

For `Map` we have the following:

`Map` -> `GenMap` -> `GenMapLike` -> `Equals` (traits hierarchy is complicated, may be another chains exist).

So we can see tha the nearest common type is `Equals`.

Second part of your puzzle is `(_)`.

This is treated by compiler as an argument of lambda:

```
val interests = x => /*omited*/.fold(Map[String, String]())(x)
```

As we saw `x` is `(A1, A1) => A1`. And in our case it is:

```
(Equals, Equals) => Equals
```

The result of `fold` is `A1` which is also `Equals`.

As a result lambda type is:

```
((Equals, Equals) => Equals) /*<< arg*/ => /*result >>*/ Equals
```

**UPDATE:**

To solve your problem I think you should use:

```
.flatten.reduce(_ ++ _)
```

Comment: Ah so Seq.fold was being used instead of Option.fold? Is flatten the way to work with Option.fold/reduce?

Comment: No. `flatten` was used to filter `None`s and extract values from `Some`s. After that extracted `Map[String, String]`s were concatenated.

Answer (score 1):

When you get a trait like `Product` or `Equals` as the inferred type of a statement, you can usually bet you have a type mismatch in some higher order function. You typically don't get `Any` or `AnyRef` because those only happen if some set of types have *nothing* in common. One thing that sticks out to me is that your 2nd argument to `fold` only takes one parameter. Amazingly enough, that typechecks, but it's probably what's giving you the types you don't expect.

I think what you wanted to do is something more like:

```
val interestRegEx = """(\w+) Interests \((.+ Interest)\)""".r
val singleAttributes = Seq("Sport Interests (Some Interest):Running,Swimming","Something else:True")
val interests = singleAttributes.map { x =>
  // e.g. ("Sport Interests (Some Interest)", "Running,Swimming") should
  // result in ("Sport Running" -> "Some Interest", "Sport Swimming" -> "Some Interest")
  val attVal = x.split(':')

  attVal(0) match {
    case interestRegEx(interestProduct, interestAmount) =>
      attVal(1).split(",").map { i =>
        Map(s"$interestProduct $i" -> interestAmount)
      }.reduce(_ ++ _)
    case _ => Map.empty
  }
}.reduce(_ ++ _)
```

For this I got:

```
scala> interests
res0: scala.collection.immutable.Map[_ <: String, String] = Map(Sport Running -> Some Interest, Sport Swimming -> Some Interest)
```

I got rid of the `Option` wrapping the `Map`s in your regex match. Since you're planning on combining the maps, may as well use the empty map as your non-match case. Then I used `reduce` instead of `fold` for your final match, much as you had done in the inner `map`.

Comment: `java.io.Serializable` is another one that type inference loves to find as a common supertype once in a while.